# jwplayer-wordpress & web browser compatibility issues

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer, wowza

I'm currently building a video streaming platform that can be viewed across virtually any device, I use windows 7 & windows 10 computers to develop with, I have several devices to test with iphone 5s/6, ipad, several android phones, android tablets, etc.

The problem is viewing m3u8 files with jwplayer on IE, Firefox & Chrome web browsers, The **only** web browser that views streams without issues is Microsoft edge, I created a WordPress web stack application using easyengine distribution & digitalocean, Installed dooplay theme (free video theme w/full activation), I registered and activated an account with jwplayer, created a player from the jwplayer dashboard, installed the jwplayer wordpress plugin, Also signed and have an active account with wowza streaming engine, Added this code to the page.php i want to view the stream.

```
<head>

<script src="https://mywebsite.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="lk/PLx6se/xvjrhSdW1SYxxxxxxxxxxxxx";</script>
```

and this to the body,

```
<body>

> <div id="player"><a
> href="rtsp://[mym3u9file]:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4">RTSP
> Link</a></div> <script>
> 
>     jwplayer("player").setup({
>         sources: [{
>             file: "http://[mym3u8file]:1935/vod/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
>         }, {
>             file: "rtmp://[mym3u8file]:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4"
>         }],
>         rtmp: {
>             bufferlength: 3
>         },
>         fallback: true
>     });
> 
> </script>
```

I found a third party plugin called jw7, bought and installed the premium verison its having the same issues, its identical to the stock jwplayer, 
So i went outside the box and used both plugins together inside the wordpress pages editor, Now i can view streams through the third party jw7 & jwplayer if the stock jwplayer wordpress plugin short code is in front of all the third party jw7 shortcode.

I can add multiple m3u8 stream files, as long as jwplayer short code is the first short code inside the editor.

```
[jwplayer gllDDbgs][jw7-video n="1"][jw7-video n="2"][jw7-video n="3"][jw7-video n="4"][jw7-video n="5"][jw7-video n="6"][jw7-video n="6"][jw7-video n="8"][jw7-video n="9"]
```

I have recreated this several times with different wordpress builds and get the same results so I dont think its a bug. I did try a few different themes as well. Next is looking into both plugins core code to reveng.

Check List:

Windows 7 computer-

1. Clean Install WordPress
2. Install [jwplayer](http://jwplayer.com) (OEM)
3. Added specified jwplayer script to page.php via SFTP
4. wordpress copy paste short code to text editor not visual editor

After doing this jwplayer works great only in fixed mode. 
Once you try and change it over to responsive mode the player says 'Error loading player:No playable sources found'.

Next,

1. Installed [jw7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jw-player-7-for-wp/) plugin
2. Added jw7 short code into wordpress text editor along with jwplayer (OEM) short code.

Now I can view streams in responsive mode but i have to use jw7 along with jwplayer. For me Jw7 plugin doesn't work by its self it needs the jwplayer OEM plugin along side it.

Any input would be great thank you.